# supertest - res/req is not defined

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I'm new to supertest and am trying to figure out a simple task.  I have a post request I'm testing, which assigns a userkey like so:

```
app.post('/game/:username', function(req, res){

    var image = req.body.image;
    var userName = req.params.username;
    var userKey = '';
    if(userName === 'player1'){
      userKey = 'player_1_id';
    } else if(userName === 'player2'){
      userKey = 'player_2_id';
    } else if(userName === 'player3'){
      userKey = 'player_3_id';
    } else {
      userKey = 'player_4_id';
    }}
```

when I try and test this, I keep getting "res is not defined" and I don't know why!

```
  it('assigns a user key properly', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .post('/game/:username')
      .send({
        image: "image/png",
        username: "player1",
        userKey: ""
      })
      .expect(201)
      .expect(res.body.should.have.property("userKey"))

    // .expect()


    .end(function(err, res) {
      if (err) return done(err);

      done();
    })

  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because you do not define `res` in your expect.

You can check `.expect(function(res) {})` document part in [github/supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest).

Try this:

```js
  it('assigns a user key properly', function(done) {
    request(app)
      .post('/game/:username')
      .send({
        image: "image/png",
        username: "player1",
        userKey: ""
      })
      .expect(201)
      .expect(function(res){
         res.body.userKey!=undefined
      })

    // .expect()


    .end(function(err, res) {
      if (err) return done(err);

      done();
    })

  })
```